# Is there a mechanism to persist older messages in Azure Event Hubs?

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, azure-eventhub

As you know, the max retention period of events on Azure Event Hubs is 90 days.
I need to persist them forever. (Something like Kafka, hot set and cold set. Being able to persist data in WAL forever)
Is there any mechanism to do that?

Comment: Azure Event Hubs is not intended to be used as a permanent storage location for infinitely held event streams. However, you can utilise the Event Hubs Capture functionality to automatically save events in Azure Blob Storage or Azure Data Lake. Refer this Document to enable Event Hub capture feature- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-capture-enable-through-portal

Comment: You could self host Kafka, instead, if this is what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Posting my comment as an answer for the benefit of the community:-***

Azure Event Hubs is not intended to be used as a permanent storage location for infinitely held event streams. However, you can utilise the **Event Hubs Capture** functionality to automatically save events in **Azure Blob Storage or Azure Data Lake**.

You can enable Event Hub Capture Feature by referring this [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-capture-enable-through-portal) like below:-

Apart from **Premium storage account** you can **save this Events in any Storage type account including ADLS Gen 2 account.** Storage account with **Hot, Cold, Archive Tier** according to your requirement can be used.

[image]

[image]